# In Java what is the "%" parameter as used in a ResultSet metadata request?

Tags: java, wildcard, resultset

In this example

```
ResultSet rsTables = metadata.getTables(null, "%", "%", tableTypes);
```

I understand the `%` stands for a wildcard but cannot find any documentation on this.  I have found documentation for `*` and `?` as wildcards, but my only experience with the `%` is as a modulus in arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters for those functions are (ultimately) used as part of an expression that uses `LIKE` in a SQL statement that retrieves the requested information.

The `%` reflects this, as it is the wildcard for multiple characters in SQL

See e.g. the [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) for an example

Comment: This is documented in the method listed in the "See also" section of getTables(), BTW: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSearchStringEscape--

Comment: Found this page, it also might mean that it will get all schemas.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS9FA_11.0.0/com.ibm.hod.doc/help/db_filter_fmt.html